# Can we use smart card authentication in Client Server Architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis, c#-4.0, smartcard

I am trying to develop ASP.Net web application to accept smart card authentication. I have created web app, deployed it in IIS. Root certificate is installed on IIS machine Trusted Root directory that is authorized by CA. For that web app, I added Server certificate, set Require SSL and set to Accept the certificates.
When, client access this web app, it prompts for client certificate, chrome gives prompt for the client certificate, smart card is inserted to client's machine, and when PIN is asked, user enters valid PIN and I am able to get home page of the web app. Till, this everything works as expected but at this point I want to read the client certificate and want to validate that client with certificate chain. Also, based on on the client certificate, I want to get the roles for that user. Everytime I try to read client certificate, I am unable to get the certificate. Below is code to read smart card certificates:

`

```
X509Store store = null;
store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certsAuthEnc = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage, (int)CertificateType.DigitalSignature, false);
```

`

Here, `store.Certificates.Count` is coming as 0.

Please help, how I can read certificates at client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the client certificate but without private key as below :

`var x509 = new X509Certificate2(this.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);`

This certificate can be validated with chain.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample, you are opening the current user "Root" store, it's not clear to me why given your description. This store only contains a list of trusted roots that have been configured by the admin and the current user.

The current user's certificates will be in the "My" store if that is what you are looking for.

If you want to validate the current users certificate in the context of the ASP.NET application for some reason you would want to use X509Chain (https://www.google.com/search?q=X509Chain&oq=X509Chain&aqs=chrome..69i57.318j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and not X509Store.

This post will probably be helpful also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148581(v=vs.110).aspx

Ryan

Comment: Thanks for your help, Why I am referring to root location is, my Login window is at server side, on my IIS server, certificates are installed on Root location.
Basically, what I am looking is, in my ASP .Net web app, when PIN is validated, I should get that digital signature data to verify next steps like if user is valid in current time stamps etc.
How can I get that digital signed data when user enters PIN ?

Comment: The root store is a list of self-signed root certificates only, you are thinking "local machine" scope not "root store". However, as I stated you do not want to be looking at the list of trust anchors you want to be validating the chain presented by the client.